# Fabric execute with SSH key?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh, fabric, python-2.x

How do I execute commands without using the `fab` utility?

#### Test case

```
from fabric.api import execute, run


def hostname():
    return run('hostname')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    execute(hostname, my_env={'key_filename': 'public_key_path'},
            hosts='{user}@{ip}'.format(user='ubuntu', ip='ip address here'))
```

#### Error

```
TypeError: hostname() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct, use `execute` to run task programmatically. The error

```
TypeError: hostname() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

means your function does not accept argument, which is `my_env`.

Just modify to:

```
def hostname(my_env):
    return run('hostname')
```

And it will work.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks. What's the correct way of passing through `env`, context managers?

Comment: You don't have to `passing through env`, `env` is accessible from everywhere.

Comment: Great. Append that to your answer also :)

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching the answer for one day. Thanks for the question asker. He/she gives a hint. And the complete solution is like this:

```
execute(hostname, hosts="{ip}", my_env={'key_filename': '~/.ssh/{pub_key}.pem', 'user' : 'ec2-user'})

def hostname(my_env):
    return run('hostname')
```

Tested and it works with my AWS instance.